# How to put Google login box inside flash in GAE?

Tags: python, flash, google-app-engine, authentication

I am putting my old flash site into GAE. I want to use Google's user authentication too. Now, I want to put Googles login box inside the flash instead of redirecting to Google's login page. Same thing I want for forgot password.

Is it possible to do this? How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Of course this is possible
you just need to use flash to post http request to your server
and your server could communicate to flash through several ways like: xml , html, and AMF or even johnson( I am not sure).

I recommend you use pyamf at server side to build a native support for flash at server side